# Discrepancy between my pandas.cut output category and the ones shown in pandas documentation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm learning pandas.cut to put my data into different bins. I'm running the example code from the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html). But somehow the category shown in the outputs I generated are different.

The first example:

```
Tocut = np.array([1, 7, 5, 6, 4, 9])
pd.cut(Tocut, 3)
```

The category output I get is "Categories (3, object): [(0.992, 3.667] < (3.667, 6.333] < (6.333, 9]]" while the documentation shows "Categories (3, interval[float64]):..."

The second example:

```
s = pd.Series(np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10]), index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
pd.cut(s, 6)
```

The category output I get is "Categories (6, object):" while the documentation still shows float64.

I am just wondering what contributes to this. And is anything in Python not an object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be a bug, but it has been fixed now. On 0.23.4, it returns float64 as expected.

```
pd.cut(s, 6)

a    (1.992, 3.333]
b    (3.333, 4.667]
c      (4.667, 6.0]
d    (7.333, 8.667]
e     (8.667, 10.0]
dtype: category
Categories (6, interval[float64]): [(1.992, 3.333] < (3.333, 4.667] < (4.667, 6.0] < (6.0, 7.333] <
                                    (7.333, 8.667] < (8.667, 10.0]]
```

Guessing it was a bug that had to do with the non-numeric index in the second example contributing to that in some way.

Comment: Thanks. Got off work before I could take a look at your reply. Just tried on my personal laptop, which had a newer version of Anaconda, and it worked. Thanks a lot. If you don't mind, could you illuminate me why it says float64 instead of object please? Isn't float number also a kind of object?Thanks.